# Returning pointers from functions

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I got caught out recently by accidentally calling a `RemoveItem` function that returned a pointer that I should have taken ownership of (but didn't), instead of calling a `DeleteItem` method which returned void.

To avoid this kind of leak, what's the right kind of pointer to return from a function where the caller is expected to take ownership of the returned object?

```
Base * factory()
{
   if (condition)
     return new DerivedA;
   else
     return new DerivedB;
 }

 ...

 boost::scoped_ptr<Base> b(factory());  // no leak here
 factory();  // but this leaks, obviously
```

Should `factory()` return a shared pointer to prevent the leak?

---

The factory example should be familiar, but here's the kind of thing that caused me a problem:-

```
void DeleteItem(ItemName);  // delete named item from structure.

Item* RemoveItem(ItemName); // removes named item from the structure, and returns it.       
                           //Caller can then re-insert it elsewhere. 

RemoveItem("Fred"); // whoops! Should have called DeleteItem.
                    // Apart from the leak, everything appears OK...
```

Comment: An `std::unique_ptr<Base>` would work. A `shared_ptr` doesn't seem to have the semantics you require.

Comment: the problem is why would you call `factory()` without getting hold of the return value from first place? I won't totally rely on tech to avoid nonsense things.

Comment: @juanchopanza - You're right, but sadly I don't have C++0x.

Comment: use `std::shared_ptr` if you don't have c++0x enabled, it might be in `std::tr1` namespace

Comment: Actually, `std::auto_ptr<Base>` might be suitable in this case.

Comment: @billz - see the updated snippet of the trap I fell into. Defensive programming should help prevent this kind of thing.

Comment: `RemoveItem` is a really misleading name..

Comment: @billz, yeah - not my choice!

Comment: The not so pretty solution is to store the pointer internally in some object that outlives the instances of `Base` and cleans up on destruction. A statically initialized factory in an unnamed `namespace` in the factory's translation unit might suffice. Of course, ownership stays with the factory and clients have no busness cleaning up stuff other than setting pointers to `nullptr` (or 0 or `NULL` for the legacy crowd). On another note, can't you just use `boost`?

Comment: If you can change the function signature why not make `RemoveItem()` require a `Item**` pointer to be passed in, then the caller is at least forced to acknowledge that a pointer is returned.

Comment: @Roddy Then use `std::auto_ptr`.  A factory function should _never_ return a `shared_ptr` (Boost or standard), because this forces the client to use `shared_ptr`, even if he doesn't want to share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious solution is to have only one function, which returns
and `std::auto_ptr` (since you say you don't have C++11).  This
will cause the object to be deleted unless the caller does
something with it.